# Write jquery code to check if the check boxes are checked or not and indicate the number of check boxes checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-plugins

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
            
             var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
               //alert(numberOfChecked);    
           // document.write(numberOfChecked);
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"/><lable>Red</lable></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"/><lable>Green</lable></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"/><lable>Blue</lable></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"/><lable>Black</lable></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p id="dem"></p>
```

This is actually an assignment oi was stuck with the dynamically changing number as im new to jquery.

Comment: Post code in your question, not screen shots.

Comment: post your codes you tried , not links .

Comment: $("input [type='checkbox']).length

Comment: @Jonasw it wont work

Comment: @Jonasw That will only return the number of checkboxes, not checked checkgboxes. See my answer below.

Comment: thank you for posting your code; I'm not sure on community policy for code posting but where are you trying to put the values you get from the checks?

Comment: Please post your code here, not a link to external sites as those links can become broken over time.

Comment: See my code changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your problem was that you were updating the count as soon as the page loads (which happens before you get a chance to check any boxes and then doesn't happen when you do check a box), not after each checkbox gets clicked.**

You asked for a JQuery solution to this problem, but understand that JQuery is just JavaScript that someone else wrote. For a trivial issue like this, adding the JQuery library really adds no value - - the problem is easily solved with straight JavaScript. JQuery is recklessly overused today. When it came out, it was much simpler than doing things without it, but that was quite a while ago and today, we can do much of the basics of JQuery just as simply without it.

```js
// Get all the checkboxes into an array
var boxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"));

// Get reference to output span
var output = document.getElementById("output");

// Loop through all the checkboxes
boxes.forEach(function(box){
  // Set up click event handlers on each
  box.addEventListener("change", function(){
    // Update the output area with the number of checked checkboxes
    output.textContent = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"> Box 1
<input type="checkbox"> Box 2
<input type="checkbox"> Box 3
<input type="checkbox"> Box 4
<div>Number checked: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

If you feel you really want a JQuery solution, here's what that would look like:

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){
     var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length; 
     $("#dem").text(numberOfChecked);  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"/><lable>Red</lable></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"/><lable>Green</lable></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"/><lable>Blue</lable></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"/><lable>Black</lable></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p id="dem"></p>
```

Comment: Your answer is definitely "correct" however one thing of note is the dude did ask for jquery specific code.

Comment: A question being tagged with JQuery doesn't mean that the answer must be in JQuery. JQuery is just JavaScript that someone else wrote. There is no reason to use it for trivial issues like this one. JQuery gets overused all the time, but "newbies" don't know any better because someone just tells them to use it. The question is also tagged with JQuery Plugins. Would you provide a plug in solution for this?

Comment: I am just going to agree on this since I don't want to write a plugin for what jquery already does effectively and efficiently. what you mentioned is hilariously true however; I know someone that only knows jquery and doesn't understand javascript at all and i'm like "wait... why would you look for a jquery array when you should look for a javascript array"

Comment: Also, remember that JQuery's API is just a wrapper around native JavaScript and the DOM API, it is impossible for JQuery to be more efficient than straight JavaScript.

Comment: Yep; I use jquery for things like ajax just to save me time in writing my code. and with a file using jquery at 4k lines of code I don't think anyone could blame me for it; but typically i'm a purist when it comes to languages without their native libraries

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox :checked")
```

this gets the checked checkboxes in an array
if you need the length of checked you can do `$(":checkbox :checked").length`

if you just do $(":checked") you get selections as well for drop down lists etc.

so you seem to have the checkbox part; what needs to be done is you need to trigger an action; where you threw the code in the javascript file runs only once. triggers are called when an event happens. 
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

since we are going by when something is checked (unless you want to tie this to a button ofc)
you would want to call it on a change

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
   $("#areaforInput").append($(":checkbox:checked").length)
});
```

with the areaForInput being the id for the object you want to append with the count for checked etc

Comment: This is true; however several people will look this up and stack is invaluable as a resource for information on this

Comment: well this is quite a common question... we dont even kon hw much he tried

Comment: touche @RiazLaskar; touche

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox"> Box 1
<input type="checkbox"> Box 2
<input type="checkbox"> Box 3
<input type="checkbox"> Box 4
<div>Number checked: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
      $("#output").text($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length);
   });
});
```

fiddle updated 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/riazxrazor/koo23g47/3/

Comment: opss...there ws a typo in `length` sorry

Comment: what i need is it should display number checked:0 should i use hide method? by printing it for the first time?

Comment: or if i unchecked all the boxeses it should displsy 0

Comment: did u check the fiddle  ? i think it is

Comment: yes my doubt  is even while refreshing my page the span tag has to show 0 as there won't be any checked boxes .for that purpose should iuse another lable tag just to display and then hide it after?

Comment: `$("#output").text($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length` just put this inside `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: i checked fiddle... but my doubt is  i should display a 0 before the page starts .for that what should i do?

Comment: before page starts means ??
btw  if u do like this `<p id="dem">0</p>` it will be there from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

> Js

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".chkBox").click(function () {
        $("#output").html($(".chkBox:checked").length)
    });
});
</script>
```

> Html

```
<input class="chkBox" type="checkbox" />Red
<input class="chkBox" type="checkbox" />Green
<input class="chkBox" type="checkbox" />Blue
<input class="chkBox" type="checkbox" />Black
<div>Number checked: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

Comment: what i need is it should display number checked:0 should i use hide method? by printingin g it

Comment: if u want to get just the number  just use                             
  $(".chkBox").click(function () {
       var lengthCount = $(".chkBox:checked").length;
    });